# Web Crawler keeps saying no attribute even though it really has

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have been developing a web-crawler for this website (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I&page=1). But I have a trouble at crawling each title of the stock. I am pretty sure that there is attribute for *carinfo_title = carinfo.find_all('a', class_='title')*.

Please check out the attached code and website code, and then give me any advice.

Thanks.

(Website Code)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxKswko3bYpuRV9seTZZT3REak0

(My code)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

target_url = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I&page=1"

def fetch_post_list():
    URL = target_url
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    html = res.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='cyber')

    #Car Info and Link
    carinfo = table.find_all('td', class_='carinfo')
    carinfo_title = carinfo.find_all('a', class_='title')

    print (carinfo_title)

    return carinfo_title

fetch_post_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *multiple elements* with the `carinfo` class and for every "carinfo" you need to get to the car title. Loop over the result of the `table.find_all('td', class_='carinfo')`:

```
for carinfo in table.find_all('td', class_='carinfo'):
    carinfo_title = carinfo.find('a', class_='title')
    print(carinfo_title.get_text())
```

Would print:

```
미니 쿠퍼 S JCW
지프 랭글러 3.8 애니버서리 70주년 에디션
...
벤츠 뉴 SLK200 블루이피션시
포르쉐 뉴 카이엔 4.8 GTS
마쯔다 MPV 2.3
```

Note that if you need only car titles, you can simplify it down to a single line:

```
print([elm.get_text() for elm in soup.select('table.cyber td.carinfo a.title')])
```

where the string inside the `.select()` method is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Comment: Thanks i figured out!! I appreciate your help.